# Trying to implement HeapSort

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, heap, heapsort

I am getting stuck on heapSort. I have some code but I think its pretty wrong since I'm having hard time compiling it. Any suggestions? Heap sort should be fairly easy to implement but I have bunch of syntax errors. Here's my code:

```
/* Framework for Heap Sort
 * CS333 Spring 2011
 * 
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 1000000
int data[MAX_SIZE];
int n;
int j;

int parent(int j) {
if(j==1)
    return 0;

if(j%2==0)
    return ( (j / 2)-1);
else
    return ( (j / 2));
}

int left(int j) {
  return (2 * j) + 1;
}

int right(int j) {
  return (2 * j) + 2;
}

void heapify(int data[], int j) {
  int l = left(j), great;
  int r = right(j);
  if ( (data[l] > data[j]) && (l < sizeof(data))) {
    great = l;
  }
  else {
    great = j;
  }
  if ( (data[r] > data[great]) && (r < sizeof(data))) {
    great = r;
  }
  if (great != j) {
    int temp = data[j];
    data[j] = data[great];
    data[great] = temp;
    heapify(data, great);
  }
}

int BuildMaxHeap(int data[]) {
  for (int j = (sizeof(data) - 1) / 2; j >= 0; j--) {
    heapify(data, j);
    return data;
  }
}

void HeapSort(int data[]) {
  BuildMaxHeap(data);
  for (int j = sizeof(data); j > 0; j--) {
    int temp = data[0];
    data[0] = data[data.sizeof() - 1];
    data[sizeof(data) - 1] = temp;
    sizeof(data) = sizeof(data) - 1;
    heapify(data, 0);
  }

}

int main()
{
  int i;

  /* Read in the data */
  n = 0;
  while (scanf("%d", &data[n]) == 1)
    ++n;
    /* Sort the numbers low to high */

     HeapSort(data);

  /* Print out the data */
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    printf("%d", data[i]);
}
```

Comment: The global variable `j` is not needed; everywhere `j` is used in a function, there is a local variable.  The global variable `n` is not needed; it should be local in `main()` and passed through to the other functions that need to know the number of elements to be sorted.  And sorting a million integers is a trifle ambitious - though once you have the code working, it will handle a million as well as a thousand (give or take the extra time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your problems seem to be in your HeapSort routine:

```
void HeapSort(int data[]) {
  BuildMaxHeap(data);
  for (int j = sizeof(data); j > 0; j--) {
```

When you pass an array to a function like this, what the function receives is actually a pointer. Using `sizeof` on that pointer will *not* tell you about the size of the data pointed to by the pointer -- it'll just tell you how many bytes the pointer itself occupies (typically 4). You probably want to pass the array size as a parameter:

```
void HeapSort(int *data, size_t data_size) {
```

and throughout the rest of the routine, you'll refer to `data_size`, not `sizeof(data)`.

```
int temp = data[0];
data[0] = data[data.sizeof() - 1];
data[sizeof(data) - 1] = temp;
sizeof(data) = sizeof(data) - 1;
```

`sizeof(whatever)` is also essentially a constant, not a variable; you can't use it as the target of an assignment (but, again, using `data_size` as suggested above *will* let you do the assignment).

Comment: what should I initialize data_size or size_t to be? The input ints will be variable sizes thnx

Comment: @user593301: From the looks of things, you're treating it as the number of elements in the array. In your `main`, it looks like you're using `n` for that. Just to be clear about it, `size_t` is a type, and `data_size` would be the parameter, of that type.